# Laravel 500 (Internal Server Error) on Ajax Post

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

I've tried doing my research on my issue but have not been able to solve it. I'm attempting to Ajax POST on click. I've read the most popular issue is due to the csrf_token, but I believe I have that handled properly?

I keep getting this error:

```
POST http://example.com/refreshCalendar 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

Here is my code...

My meta tag for the csrf token at the top of my master.blade.php file

```
<meta name="token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

Route:

```
Route::post('/refreshCalendar', ['as' => 'refreshCalendar', 'uses' =>'Calendar@refreshCalendar']);
```

Js function

```
function refreshCalendar(obj){
var month = obj.data('month');
var year = obj.data('year');
history.pushState(null, null, '/month/'+month+'/year/'+year);

var data = {
    "month":month,
    "year":year,
    _token:$('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
 };

$.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: '/refreshCalendar',
     dataType: 'html', 
     async:true,
     data: data,
     success: function(data){
             $('#calendarHolder').html(data);

     },
     error: function(){alert("There was an error retrieving information");return false;}
 });
```

}

My Controller:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use DateTime;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;  

class Calendar extends Controller
{


public function refreshCalendar(Request $request)
    {
        //Set data to $request
        $data = $request->all();
        return show($data['month'], $data['year'], true);
    }

}
```

Comment: What the response body for your failed request? Use you browsers network inspector to read the error.

Comment: You talking about what it says in the console.log?

It alerts me the "There was an error retrieving information" but the console.log says "POST http://example.com/refreshCalendar 500 (Internal Server Error)"

Comment: Use the browser's debugger to see what is really send to the server. It might contain clues. Try turning off CSRF check for this route and see what happens.

Comment: Try looking in `/storage/log/laravel.log` for Laravel errors and post the most recent one here. My best guess would be your show() method not being defined

Comment: I commented out // \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class, and its working properly... I guess it still has something to do with the token?

Answer (score 1):

```
<meta name="token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
_token:$('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
```

Your meta tag name is `token`, however you are looking for the meta tag named `csrf-token`.

Answer (score 0):

If `meta` is present, you should look to your network for issues.

That was the culprit for me:

[image: such as here]